# Why does firefox asks for a squid password everytime I open a new tab?

Tags: authentication, firefox, centos7, squid

I'm trying to prevent firefox from constantly asking for a new authentication when a new tab is opened.
Moreover in the configuration of firefox it is necessary to specify the page without proxy, but it still asks for an authentication.

The squid server is under centos 7 and the PC client use firefox version 52.7.2
can anyone help me?

Is something wrong with my squid.conf configuration file here :

-----------------------squid.conf----------------------------------------
debug_options ALL,1
http_port 3128
logfile_rotate 30
maximum_object_size 32 MB
icp_port 0
acl QUERY urlpath_regex cgi-bin \?
no_cache deny QUERY
cache_store_log none
access_log /var/log/squid/access.log squid

visible_hostname my_server.domain.com
acl domain1 dstdomain .domain1.com
http_access allow domain1
acl domain2 dstdomain .domain2.com
http_access allow domain2
auth_param basic program /usr/lib64/squid/basic_ldap_auth -b "ou=People,dc=mycompany,dc=com" -f "uid=%s" -u uid -D "uid=xxx,ou=xxx,dc=mycompany,dc=com" -w "password" -h ldap://myldap.com
auth_param basic children 350
auth_param basic realm Web-Proxy
auth_param basic credentialsttl 2 hours

acl  if_ok src "/etc/squid/conf/default/ipadress"

acl BlockedHost_mdl src "/etc/squid/mdl.txt"
http_access deny  BlockedHost_mdl
acl BlockedHost_bruteforceblocker src "/etc/squid/bruteforceblocker.txt"
http_access deny BlockedHost_bruteforceblocker
acl BlockedHost_shdrop src "/etc/squid/shdrop.txt"
http_access deny BlockedHost_shdrop
acl internet proxy_auth REQUIRED
acl internet_domains dstdomain -i "/etc/squid/conf/internet/domains"
http_access allow internet
http_access allow if_ok
http_access allow localhost
http_access deny all